# Java Date set the minutes and seconds to 0

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, minute

I want to set the  minutes and seconds of a date to 0,
but I see that those methods are deprecated

```
Date yesterday = Date.from(Instant.now().minus(24, ChronoUnit.HOURS));

    yesterday.setMinutes(0);
                yesterday.setSeconds(0);
```

Comment: You are using the `Date` class, but in Java 8 you should not do that. It’s poorly designed and long outdated. Stick with `Instant` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). And use `yesterday = yesterday.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

```
    ZonedDateTime yesterday = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Madrid"))
            .minusDays(1)
            .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS);
    System.out.println("Yesterday with minutes and seconds set to 0: " + yesterday);
```

Running just now gave

> Yesterday with minutes and seconds set to 0: 2019-03-17T23:00+01:00[Europe/Madrid]

### Define yesterday

If you intended “yesterday at the same time”, that’s not always 24 hours ago. Due to summer time (DST) and other anomalies, a day may be for example 23, 23,5 or 25 hours.

### java.time

The `ZonedDateTime` class of java.time, the modern Java date and time API, takes the time anomalies in your time zone into account. So when you subtract a day, you do get the same time yesterday, if that time exists at all.

`.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS)` sets minutes, seconds and fraction of second to 0 in the time zone in question.

You were trying to use the `Date` class, but in Java 8 you should not do that. It’s poorly designed and long outdated. I find java.time so much nicer to work with.

### If you indispensably need an old-fashioned Date

You may need a `Date` for a legacy API that you cannot change or cannot afford to change just now. In that case convert only in the last moment:

```
    Instant yesterdayInstant = yesterday.toInstant();
    Date yesterdayDate = Date.from(yesterdayInstant);
    System.out.println("As old-fashoined Date: " + yesterdayDate);
```

In my time zone (Europe/Copenhagen, currently agrees with Europe/Madrid) I got

> As old-fashoined Date: Sun Mar 17 23:00:00 CET 2019

### Link

[Oracle Tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.